# Different branch with one unique file in git

Tags: git, bitbucket, except

I have a project with a git server . We are two dev working on it and each of us have to use a different token for some api. I also have one other api key for my master branch, dev branch and testing branch.
All the api tokens are stocked in a config.json file, which means 5 differents config.json.

The problem is : I want to have my config.json unchanged when push or merge one branch commit to another.

I have try some solution with the .gitignore file and `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.json` but none of them seems to be adapted to my case. 
I have also found the .git/info/except file, who really seems to be what I need but whatever I try, the config.json appear "modified".

So if you have a possible solution, other than that, or the reason why my exept do not work, it would be really helpful!

Regards, Eiji

---

"Lack of better" Solution :

I have use the solution of @gus3001.
I have made a folder configs with all the differents configs (dev / master / testing / etc) in it, and another, preset.json, which is referenced in .gitignore.

So on each branch switch, we just have to modify a short string in the ignored file.
It still can be confusing and risky, so if you have a better solution, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would normally solve this problem is to place user-dependent configuration in a separate file. So in you case, I would take the api-token out of the `config.json` and put it in an git-ignored file, something called `user-config.json` perhaps.

This will likely mean that you have to change your code to get the token from the new `user-config.json`, but the benefit is that you can actually track the non-user-dependent config in `config.json` normally, without worrying about making it ignored by git only when the token is different but not when something else has changed.

**tl;dr**

User dependent config should be in a separate git-ignored file to avoid such issues.

Comment: So it means 5 differents X-config.json instead of one?

Comment: What I mean is, each user will have their own config, which will not be commited. So, you will not see other peoples configs in the repo. You will just see your own in a user-config.json which is just local.

Comment: The idea is to separate things that change from things that dont.

Comment: But all the problem is we have to run the script on our pc. Sometimes, we use our version (own branch), sometime (for the test for exemple) we run the testing version. 
If I don't commit the file and ignore it, when we switch, we have to change our version of the config with the correct config.json each time we switch on a branch... Which can create confusion or worst... like run a bugged version of the script on the client api key... And that case can be really problematic...

Comment: Well, lack of better, I have use your solution @gus3001.
I have made a folder configs with all the differents configs (dev / master / testing / etc) in it, and another, preset.json, which is referenced in .gitignore.

So on each branch switch, we just have to modify a short string in the ignored file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [`skip-worktree` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit):

> The `skip-worktree` bit can be defined in one (long) sentence: when reading an entry, if it is marked as `skip-worktree`, then Git pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead.

You can set the `skip-worktree` flag on your `config.json` file by saying:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree config.json
```

#### Skip Worktree vs. Assume Unchanged

The `skip-worktree` flag is different from [`assume-unchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit) in that `assume-unchanged` implies that Git *won't check* a given file for modifications in the working directory because it assumes the file *hasn't changed*:

> You can set "assume unchanged" bit to paths you have not changed to cause Git not to do this check. Note that setting this bit on a path does not mean Git will check the contents of the file to see if it has changed — it makes Git to omit any checking and assume it has **not** changed.

The documentation further [clarifies this point](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#git-update-index---no-assume-unchanged):

> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index.

The `assume-unchanged` flag is really a *performance optimization* if you happen to be on a file system that's unusually slow to compare files<sup>1</sup> or—way more likely—if you're dealing with *large* files that don't change very often.

The `skip-worktree` flag, on the other hand, tells Git to completely *ignore* the copy of the file that's in the working directory and rely only on what has been recorded in the index. For this reason `skip-worktree` has *higher priority* than `assume-unchanged` if both are set on a given file. Also, it's worth noting that `assume-unchanged` is unset whenever the file is modified upstream while `skip-worktree` is maintained until you manually unset it.

---

1. Honestly, I can't think of any modern file system that would fit that description.

Comment: If I have correctly understood the doc, this could be my solution! I try that.

Comment: Hmm after a try :
I create a branch `diverge`, child of the develop branch and modify the config.json. No changes appear to be seen but when I try to switch branch, the classic commit message error appear. :/ So it's not good in my case.
But thanks, I learn a new feature.